# Entity framework FK not updating on cascade delete

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-5

I am currently using Entity Framework 5,  and this is a rather simple problem.   I have two types that have Recipients as a reference.

```
public File() : base()
{
    this.Preview = FilePreview.None;
    this.Recipients = new HashSet<SharedFileRecipient>();
}

public Folder() : base()
{
    this.Preview = FilePreview.None;
    this.Recipients = new HashSet<SharedFileRecipient>();
}
```

SharedFileRecipient is just a regular C# class with a few properties, and does NOT specify references back to File or Folder.

In the database EF maps all of this fine,  including adding two nullable FKs (File_Id and Folder_Id) to the dbo.SharedFileRecipients table which point back to either dbo.File or dbo.Folder.

So far so good,  but at runtime when we try to delete a File or a Folder that has been shared then the database throws an error

"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_dbo.SharedFileRecipient_dbo.Folder_Folder_Id\".

I know this is because EF is not running an update on dbo.SharedFileRecipients making the File_Id and Folder_Id columns null before it goes on to delete the parent object.

How do we tell EF that this needs to happen?    And also, if I actually wanted to force cascade deletes on File/Folders so that SharedFileRecipients would go away on deletes, how to tell EF this?

I've read plenty of articles on setting it up using the Fluent API, but I dont think that applies to my very simple model. As I would have to actually (and explicitly) declare foreign key properties on SharedFileRecipient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must load the related `Recipients` from the database. It doesn't matter if you do this with eager, lazy or explicit loading. Once the children are loaded and attached to the context EF will send UPDATE statements to the database that set the children's foreign keys to NULL when you delete the parent. For example with eager loading:

```
var file = context.Files.Include(f => f.Recipients).Single(f => f.Id == someId);
context.Files.Remove(file);
```

There is no configuration that would achieve this automatically. The key is to attach the related children to the context.

If you want to setup cascading delete for your (optional) relationship you can use this configuration with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<File>()
    .HasMany(f => f.Recipients)
    .WithOptional()
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```